# Thymeleaf HREF server context

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this href in a button that is working fine

```
<input type="button" value="CANCEL" th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/user/list/} + '\''"  />
```

nevertheless I have a href, where I have to put also the `server.servlet.context-path` defined the the `application.properties` file, otherwise the link goes to `http://127.0.0.1/user/list`

```
 <a href="/myapp/user/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                       <i class="fa fa-id-card-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; USERS
                   </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `th:href` just like you're doing for your JavaScript:

```
<a th:href="@{/user/list/}" class="pure-menu-link">
  <i class="fa fa-id-card-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; USERS
</a>
```